# Cannot cannot create app using npx create-react-app appname

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, npx

this is the error i am facing while creating react app.
[image]

**I had tried below solution but it doesnot work for me**
updated my npm using below command

`npm i -g npm@latest`

`npm cache clear --force`

`yarn cache clear`

`npx create-react-app myapp --use-npm`

*I also check .npmrc folder in C:user>me> but still it not working*

**Node version**
`v16.15.0`

**Npm version**
`8.13.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use **--use-npm**

Simply use

> npx create-react-app app-name

Comment: i have also tried this but give me same error

Comment: try to remove the node.js which is responsible for **node_modules** and install it again. and try. to check also your internet connection. Sometimes it fails because of the internet connection.

Comment: how to remove npm ,yarn and node form my computer

Comment: npm and yarn are both different things but they are used for the same purpose which is downloading 3rd packages. you should decide to use only one thing from both of them that's first. to remove the node. I think you can go to the program files for your computer and scroll until you find the node. delete it. and install it again. Remember to use it after removing the node. yarn or npm.

Comment: ok i have uninstall it form control panel . I will again install it and try to create react app